# debugging solutions for opera and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, opera

Searching for solution or methods of debugging my jquery script under the Opera/IE browser. Seems that its not send ajax `$.post()` request or send it to incorrect address or something similar. There is no problems at Firefox. Maybe somebody know addons or other hacks to check what actual data send by the browser at buckground (request headers, answers)? 
Where is something similar to Firefox Javascript Console at Opera and Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera has a developer-tool called Dragonfly. Simply rightclick anywhere on your page and select "Inspect element". Here you have console, inspector mode, NET and so on. Everything you need.

IE also has a developer tool. You access this by hitting F12.

Based on what you need, these tools should be enough.

Comment: Hmm, well, then I would advice him to upgrade to IE9, because it is capable of displaying both 9, 8, 7 and also something that reminds me of IE6. If this is impossible, fiddler2 would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I use fiddler2, its brilliant and will work with all browsers as it is a standalone application.

[Fiddler2 Web debugging proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 0):

As OptimusCrime says there is a developer tool in IE.

It's worth mentioning that IE (7 and 8) will throw an error if the tool is disabled and there is any reference to the `console` in your code.